# Skrollr does sudden jerk instead of smooth scroll

Tags: jquery, css, skrollr

Can you help me figure out why skrollr (parallax scrolling) isn't working on this page?

http://adoptastar.whitedwarf.org

When logged in with an admin bar at the top, I can scroll all the way to the bottom, and toward the end there will be a jump where the background stars move. When there's no admin bar, there isn't even a jump. How can I make the background layers scroll smoothly like at http://adoptastar.whitedwarf.org/parallax/?

I've tried adding

```
height: 100%;
```

to html, body, #wrapper, and #container, to no avail. And sometimes adding this screws up the navigation bar anchors, like http://adoptastar.whitedwarf.org/#adopt, in Safari (the bottom of #container will jump up above the bottom of the page, and content within #container will appear beyond the bottom of #container).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a unit for the background position, which skrollr requires

Wrong

```
data-0="background-position: 0 0;"
```

Right

```
data-0="background-position: 0 0px;"
```